# Every sub page shows Error 404, i have check permalink but still same issues

Tags: permalinks, 404-error

i have no idea what is the issues with wordpress setup, every subpages is showing Error 404, except main pages, for all your reference i have attached admin panel images to understand the flow, i have check .htaccess too, but still same issues., can any one help me to sort out the issues.

.htaccess code

```
 # BEGIN WordPress
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /fev/
 RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule . /fev/index.php [L]
 </IfModule>
 # END WordPress
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1) In settings>Permalinks save again the permalinks and check again.
2) There is some custom permalinks plugin installed I see from the screenshot you attached, please check there and try to save the permalinks.

Comment: Hi Vivek, i have done many times since same issues..,

Comment: if you want i can share you admin details to check the issues, or you can guide me how i can solve the issues.., i am totally confused..

Comment: Okay, please share your details: contact[at]codeinsol.com

Comment: i have sent mail, plz check

Comment: i think you wrong in .htaccess RewriteBase. remove htaccess  or put default code and check.

Comment: i tried everything dear, used default code but not working